# Grid Editing in shieldUI lite api

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, datagrid, shieldui

I have created a dynamic grid by using ShieldUI API and added dropdown boxes to each colunm.

Initial grid:
[image]

But when I am adding new row then previous rows values are being reset to null.According to my understanding this is happening because dropdown values are not being set into existing grid:

[image]

And when I am clicking on grid anywhere then the grid row is freezing and row values are retained.

I am using custom editor for dropdown like:

```
function subAccountCustomEditor(cell, item) 
{ 
    $('<div id="subAccount"/>')
        .appendTo(cell)
        .shieldDropDown({
            dataSource: { data: [] }, 
            value: !item["subAccount"] ? null : item["subAccount"].toString(),
            textTemplate: "{value}", 
            valueTemplate: "{code}", 
            inputTemplate: "{value}"
        }).swidget().focus(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the following example:
http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-editing/editing-custom-editor

To see how to initialize a custom editor. In this case it is a combo, but the same logic is applicable for a drop-down or any other widget.

Comment: Thank for suggestion !

Comment: But I have already gone through this example...Actually I am looking for batch insert and update. If I am adding a single row then there is problem but when I am adding multiple rows then previous row yield null values in the existing grid.

Comment: I am looking an option by which I can make that particular row deselect when clicking on insert button.  In this case values will be retain while adding new row.